# Show ALV grid as Crystal Report by default

Tags: crystal-reports, abap, alv

In the views push button of the ALV we have you can choose Crystal Report to show the grid in a crystal report format

[image]

And it would result something like this:

[image]

I want to show the Crystal report view to the user from the beginning instead of showing the ALV grid and choosing CR view manually. Is there a way?

Comment: How do you create and call the ALV?

Comment: I have followed this link: https://scn.sap.com/thread/616304. So I have my data in an internal table and have put it to the alv grid from the examples. so what I want to achieve it to just show my data in a crystal report form not in the alv grid. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Use this button on the ALV toolbar

[image: click here to see image]

and choose "Save Layout" option

[image: click here to see image]

Fill layout and name, and make sure that `default` check-box is selected.

Comment: I suppose this will not work. Dunno about Crystal for sure, but changing ALV representation mode to List re-initializes the whole layout framework and all layout variants including default are invalidated.